# How to loop an argument to multiple structs with identical names?

Tags: c++, struct

I'm fairly new to coding and c++ and was working on a base maze game and making
it more efficient across the whole thing.

My question is basically instead of writing the same thing over and over to
define multiple structs the same way can I make something with an int on the
end that increments by 1 every loop to take position of the struct name somehow
or is this not possible?

This is my code if you are still confused by my poor explanation.

```
for (int g = 1; g < 30; g++)
{
    if (    (x == wall(g).x && y == wall(g).y) 
            && (player.x + 1 == wall1.x && player.y == wall1.y))
    {
    }
}
```

Above is the approximate idea I have come up.

I have declared many structs named (wall1, wall2, wall3, etc) at the top that
need to all run this argument.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to add a number to a symbol name at runtime... My best idea would be for you to put your structs into an array that you can index by number

Comment: That's called an "array".

Comment: It's nice of you to consider that our confusion might have to do with poor explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array of *struct* and using index you can access to your desired *struct* in the runtime. 
You also can try using *switch-case*. 
That's all I have to help you.

Comment: Thanks man like I said I'm only 16 and just learning a lot of this stuff but this helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit all your structs from a single ancestor and use a base pointer.
Alternatively, if you need to know the exact struct type, you can use RTTI.
But, of course, they cant have identical name.